# OpenOffice won't start

Tags: unity

I click on the shortcut and nothing happens.  This goes for all Openoffice programs.   I've even tries to launch the exe directly.  None of the openoffice modules will start on my computer.  I can open the files just fine on another computer, so I know it's not the network or the file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a .exe file in ubuntu this is a windows specific file format.
Open office an its pendant libre office can  be downloaded as a seperate ubuntu/linux version. You can identify the selfextracting packages unter ubuntu by the ending .deb.
Here's the download site with open office for [all available platforms](http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html). Be sure to select the suitable platform (64-bit versions are usually marked as x86-versions)

So in short words: exe = windows; deb = linux

There are of course ways to execute an .exe file on linux, further information you can get googling for wineHQ, but for open office this is not necessary

Comment: Actually, `.deb` is for *Debian* based Linux (Ubuntu being a Debian based distro).  Red Hat and Fedora use `.rpm` for example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct and if you want open office then go to the terminal and type in these comamnds:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

Or you could install wine which reads .exe files (not good at some files though)

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Or you could try libre office which is pre-installed on Ubuntu, and is based off OpenOffice

I hope this helps.